# Desabilitar edição de dataset FireDAC sem gerar exceção

Tags: delphi, firedac

Suponhamos que um `FDQuery` com um `select` simples esteja ligado com um `DBGrid`.
 Quero impedir que o usuário faça qualquer edição no registro.
Sei que há a opção `EnableDelete` no `FDQuery`, porém caso o usuário tente apagar o registro, por exemplo, o `FireDAC` gerará uma exceção.
Tem como impedir a Edição/Inserção/Exclusão sem gerar uma exceção?

Esse controle não pode ser feito no `DBGrid`, tem que ser feito no `Dataset`.

Mais detalhes:

- Delphi XE7
- Firebird 2.5
- Quero fazer uma solução genérica porque estou com esse problema em
  várias telas e tenho uso o `FDQuery` num **componente herdado**, aplicar
  a solução nesse componente herdado resolveria meu problema em todas
  as telas do sistema.

Comment: Qual exceção está sendo disparada quando o usuário tenta excluir no `DBGrid`?

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr A exceção nativa do FireDAC: **[FireDAC][Comp][DS]-215. Record deleting for dataset [Query1] is disabled.**

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Editei a pergunta....

Comment: Neste caso você teria que herdar também o `DBGrid` ai você faria a configuração do `ReadOnly` apenas uma vez também?

Comment: Concordo com você que seria uma boa solução, mas não posso alterar todos os `dbgrid´s` do meu sistema a essa altura. A solução precisa ser aplicada no Dataset (`FDQuery`). @CelsoMarigoJr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitui o evento `DoBeforeDelete` do `FDQuery`.
Nesse evento, verifico se a propriedade `EnableDelete` está desmarcada e se estiver, apenas executo o comando `Abort`.
Pode parecer um pouco radical, mas faz a mesma coisa que o **FireDAC**, porém sem gerar uma exceção para o usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar deixar seu `DBGrid` como `ReadOnly`, veja se existe essa propriedade no seu Delphi. Qual delphi está usando?

Talvez isso já resolva:

```
With DBGrid1
.AllowAddNew = False
.AllowDelete = False
.AllowUpdate = False
End With
```

Caso não funcione nada disso, programe o evento `OnKeyPress` ou `OnKeyDown` para ignorar qualquer tecla.

Comment: eu agradeço sua ajuda, mas apesar de funcional não é bem o que estou procurando, veja a edição que fiz na minha pergunta por favor.